# activity aggregate relationships only allow security evaluation for non-admin users when a single parent record is evaluated

Tags: soql, relationships, aggregate

I am getting the following error when I run a Salesforce SOQL query with a standard account.
**Query**:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT Id, Subject FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate
ASC , LastModifiedDate DESC  LIMIT 500) FROM Account WHERE Id in (
'001b0000009owSN', '001b0000009owNo' )
```

**Results**:
MALFORMED_QUERY: Implementation restriction: activity aggregate relationships only allow security evaluation for non-admin users when a single parent record is evaluated

Same query under Admin account works well.

Similar query works well under Standard account:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts ORDER BY Email ASC  LIMIT 500)
FROM Account WHERE Id in ( '001b0000009owSN', '001b0000009owNo' )
```

How can the problematic query be re-written?
Why does  that limitation exists?

Thanks,

Comment: Same question on StackOverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921044/activity-aggregate-relationships-only-allow-security-evaluation-for-non-admin-us

Answer (score 3):

Do you know if you are using `with sharing` on the apex classes?

The implication from [SOQL Query ActivityHistory Problem](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gj3GAAQ) is that switching to the System context will bypass the non-admin user restriction.

As a guess, I'd say it is too expensive for Salesforce to evaluate if a non-admin user has access to the referenced ActivityHistory records. Where is an admin doesn't require the same level of access checking.

Failing that, can you split the query into two parts or query ActivityHistory rather than OpenActivities?

<strike>Set accountIds = new Set();
    accountIds.add('001b0000009owSN');
    accountIds.add('001b0000009owNo');
    // What fields do you actually want from Account?
    List accounts = [Select Id, Name from Account where ID in :accountIds];
    List activities = [Select Id, AccountId, Subject 
                                     FROM OpenActivities 
                                     ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC, LastModifiedDate DESC 
                                     WHERE AccountId in :accountIds
                                     LIMIT 500];</strike>

See also [OpenActivity - Usage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_objects_openactivity.htm):

> The following restrictions on users who don’t have “View All Data” permission help prevent performance issues:
>
> - **In the main clause of the relationship query, you can reference only one record**. For example, you can’t filter on all records where the account name starts with ‘A’; instead, you must reference a single account record.
> - You can’t use WHERE clauses.
> - You must specify a limit of 499 or fewer on the number of rows returned in the list.
> - You must sort on ActivityDate in ascending order and LastModifiedDate in descending order; you can display nulls last. For example: `ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC NULLS LAST, LastModifiedDate DESC`.

Comment: Regarding the `"with sharing"`, the SOQL above is used via API and not in APEX.

Comment: Naturally, this is a Salesforce performance restriction. But, why would the SAME SOQL structure work for other objects as notes in the question? Why would this object be treated differently?

Comment: re: Spliting: not sure what you mean.

Comment: Querying other objects: maybe it wll work, but the same problem exists with other objects as well. For example the following query also fails with the same error:
`SELECT  ( SELECT Id, Subject, Who.Name, What.Name, IsTask, ActivityDate, Owner.Name, LastModifiedDate, Account.Name FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC , LastModifiedDate DESC  LIMIT 500) FROM Account WHERE Id in ( '001b0000009owSN', '001b0000009owNo' ) `

Comment: re the "...reference only one record...", implies that queries that do work, shouldn't. For example, the 2nd example in the original question

Comment: OpenActivity and ActivityHistory aren't strictly objects in Salesforce. Think of them more like read only views that aggregate data from several other tables. Something about the way they are implemented internally at Salesforce restricts them to only working with a single record at a time. Exactly what that is would require knowledge of how Salesforce have implemented them.

Comment: BTW, the same SOQL with one record (outer section) using WHERE works fine: For example:  
`SELECT  ( SELECT Id, Subject FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY  ActivityDate
 ASC , LastModifiedDate DESC  LIMIT 500) FROM Account WHERE Id ='001b0000009owSN'`

Comment: Yes, OpenActivity working with only one Id is consistent with the documentation I have linked to and quoted in my answer.

Comment: I agree it is consistent with the documentation. I am still wondering why it is not consistent across all objects. As you mentioned, probably some internal performance reasons.